# why gentoo livecd can not detect the linked network card?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, gentoo

The original os is Ubuntu 12.04, machine has 4 network cards, and the first netcard is linked.

If use `ethtool`, will get `Link detected: yes`.

When I use `gentoo livecd` to start, and config network, I found in gentoo livecd, the network card is `Link detected: no` by ethtool, so I can't up the network, I have tried all the four network cards.

I don't know why in gentoo livecd, the first network card is deteched not linked?

Does it related to the network driver?

Comment: what lscpi shows up with on live cd?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is the installed OS not bootable?

Comment: @DanilaLadner @Andrew Sorry, That's my default, if the netcard is not up, the `Link detected` will show `no`. But after all, the origin reason is miss a bnx2 module, so the network card can't up.

Answer (score 0):

That's my default, if the netcard is not up, the `Link detected` will show `no`.

But after all, the origin reason is miss a bnx2 module, so the network card can't up.